# Association with the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, associations, mongoid

I have two models 'Product' and 'Variant',product has many variants,now I have to set assocaiation of a new Model named as "Ingridient" with variant in such a way that Variant has many ingridients.but in ingridents I want to show that it again has_one product and variant.for example

```
 class Variant
  has_many :ingridients
  belongs_to :product
end

class Ingridient
 belongs_to :variant
 belongs_to :product
end
```

now in my ingrident model I also want has_one variant and has_one product at the same time.how should I set my associations.I know multiple association with same table but dont know how to implement it in my app.Iam using mongoid as my database.

Edit : Actually in my flow User can create a Product with many variants and then each variant can have multiple ingridients.In that each ingrident i have select box for selecting products and variants form database .means ingridients will consist a product a variant ,quantity etc fields .To make it more clear Iam making a Recipe 
.

Comment: Why do you need `has_one`? You can access the same variant by calling `self.variant` from inside `Ingredient`. How are both different?

Comment: actually in my data flow,I acn create a Product with multiple variants,then i have multiple ingridients for each varients.and in ingridients i have a select box to select product_name and variant_name again from databse.so each ingridient shall consist one product and one variant.

Comment: And that can't be accomplished with `belongs_to` ?

Comment: yes we can do it as well but do you have any idea how to do that?there will be 2 belongs to for product and variant model but with diff name.

Comment: I mean you don't need 2 `belongs_to` for `:product`. Why do you think you need two?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% clear on what you want to do.

But what it looks like is that you want to have a association with a different name.

```
class Variant
  has_many :ingridients, :foreign_key => 'FieldName', :class_name => 'CassName'
  belongs_to :product, :foreign_key => 'FieldName', :class_name => "CassName"
end

class Ingridient
 belongs_to :variant, :foreign_key => 'FieldName', :class_name => "CassName"
 belongs_to :product, :foreign_key => 'FieldName', :class_name => "CassName"
end
```

I hope that this helps

Comment: Yeah your answer is very close to what i want.but can i have like variant has_many :ingridents and at the same time ingrident belongs_to :variant and also belongs_to :variant,forign_key => 'Fieldname',:class_name => "Classname"?